# Weblogic 12c managed server not able to start from console but able to stop from console

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Hi My current environment is Weblogic 12c Std 
i have 2 servers which is running one Admin server 2 managed servers
Node -1  contains admin & 1 managed servers 
Node -2 contains Managed servers

My issues is i am able to stop node-2 managed server node 2 from Admin console but not able to start from Admin console

**While start i am getting below Error on Console**

Message icon - Warning For server mrm_node2, the Node Manager associated with machine mrm_machine2 is not reachable.
Message icon - Warning All of the servers selected are currently in a state which is incompatible with this operation or are not associated with a running Node Manager or you are not authorized to perform the action requested. No action will be performed.

In Adminserver log i am getting below warning

#### <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1505972472314>

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1505972472314>  

     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1505972472314>  

     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1505972472315>

Note:-- I enrolled NM Control on Node-2 also

Answer (score 1):

To be able to start a Managed Server via the Admin Server, the Node Manager needs to be running and obviously be reachable.

You can start the Node Manager with the `startNodeManager.sh` script in `<weblogic-home>/server/bin`.

If the Managed Server is already running you can shut it down through the Admin Server even without the Node Manager, because then the Managed Server is already in communication with the Admin Server.

Comment: Hi I tried that one also from Node-2 i have started Node manager through CLI and from admin console try to start Managed serve 2 but I am not able to start Managed server

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the configuration of your Node Manager. Check the Node Manager log in the admin console in `Environment | Machines | <your-machine> | Monitoring | Node Manager Log`. It is hard to know how your system is set up because your description is not clear. @Kumar

Comment: Hi yes i figured it out i enabled SSL in Node-2, in node-1 i configured PLAIN socket now both i enabled PLAIN now able to communicate